# how to select radio button using swipe gesture in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, radio-button, uigesturerecognizer

How to **Select radio button by using swipe gesture** instate of tapping on radio button, 
How to do it?
I have to select option from radio group using swiping finger on that particular option.
Current I am doing using conventional method by tapping on radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/1665266) link. use radio button view instead of ImageView used in example. I have used it, it works.